# Molar Mass & Pressure-Volume Relationship

Tags: gas-laws

How do differences in molar mass affect the pressure-volume relationship between four different gases?

Comment: Always think  thoroughly about possible answers to your question and search for them in textbooks/ this site and generally on internet before asking. This would prevent redundant information provided in eventual answers.

Answer (score 1):

Under ideal conditions smaller molecules will move faster and have more collisions which will increase pressure and volume. If pressure increases, the molecules have less free space to move and volumes may increase slightly beyond what the ideal gas law predicts. If volume decreases and molecules have less space to move, intermolecular forces can come into play and decrease the force with which collisions occur which will cause the pressure to be less than ideal gas law predictions. Larger masses, larger force of collision.
A lot of circumstances to consider.